# How can I access the Microsoft Graph API with the B2C currently logged in user's credentials

Tags: openid, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure Active Directory B2C with policies defined and an application registered in the B2C blade. I can use the OWIN pipeline within my .NET web application to sign a user into the application. But, that user doesn't seem to be able to access the Graph API with the JWT sent back from the AAD B2C.

The first issue seems to be the scopes that are available. In my OWIN setup in the Startup.Auth.cs in my application, I have this code:

```
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppId"];
    private static string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppSecret"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AadInstance"];
    private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
    private static string graphScopes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:GraphScopes"];

    // B2C policy identifiers
    public static string SignUpPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignUpPolicyId"];
    public static string SignInPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignInPolicyId"];

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        // Configure OpenID Connect middleware for each policy
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignUpPolicyId));
        //app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ProfilePolicyId));
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId));
    }
```

Later in this file, I have this:

```
        private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
    {
        return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
            // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
            MetadataAddress = String.Format(aadInstance, tenant, policy),
            AuthenticationType = policy,

            // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
            ClientId = clientId,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
            },
            Scope = "openid profile offline_access",
            ResponseType = "id_token",

            // This piece is optional - it is used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                SaveSigninToken = true,
            },
        };
    }
```

Where I set the scope, I tried using one of the scopes from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes) in order to later access the graph. That gave me an invalid request error.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Microsoft Graph does not support tokens issued by AAD B2C. This is something we'll be looking to fix over time.  In the meantime you'll need to acquire tokens from the regular AAD STS (either from the v1 or the v2 endpoint).  Please see https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/auth_overview

Hope this helps,

Comment: Can you clarify what Microsoft public documentation  clearly states that B2C tokens cannot be used with Microsoft Graph?